# ODBC connection is extremely slow

Tags: odbc

I have an ODBC connection to a providex database. We use the database in software throughout the company, and the ODBC connection is created by a standard installer.

Trying to test the ODBC connection or query it in Crystal Reports.Net, results in the program or ODBC admin locking up for about 10 minutes before finally returning with the query or test result. This problem has only been happening on my pc.

There's an ODBC connection to a different database that works just fine, as well.

Has anyone else run into this problem and/or found a solution?

Comment: Came across this thread, having the same problem. @TonyPeterson: do you remember the services you switched off? Problem is that sometimes the program works fine, some other times it doesn't... Arrrhhhh TIA

Comment: It was 10 years ago when we figured this out. I don't remember what services were turned off. We still use the same providex database for Sage 100 ERP, but we haven't had much trouble since then.

Answer (score 3):

Still if you are facing the issue, please see blow resolution:

### Root Cause

The issue which we were seeing on Win7 VDIs could be due to the Network hardware device connected with the machine. If TCP/IP scaling is  not supported by the network device then the performance will be slow.

### Solution

Disable auto tuning level of the TCP. Please follow below steps:
1)  Open command Prompt with admin right (Run as Admin)
2)  Type “netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled”
3)  After running above command restart the machine.

For other information on this command, visit  link “http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935400”

Answer (score 2):

Can you run Wireshark during this behavior on your machine and see if anything jumps out at you? Try it on the server as well, if you can.

I don't know anything about Providex specfically, perhaps there's some tracing you can turn on at the client to help you figure this out?

Comment: The problem went away when we turned off a bunch of services, and then oddly, it didn't come back. I had restarted the PC several times before that without fixing the problem. If the problem comes back I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

If both machines uses the same driver to connect the same server then probably something is wrong with network (maybe antivirus software checks something, maybe firewall etc).

To check on what ODBC "stops" I would use ODBC trace. In ODBC manager you can enable trace. Then compare traces from machine where ODBC works well and from machine where ODBC works slow. Unfortunately on my machine there is no timestamp for each log entry, but if there were some errors on the "slow" machine you will see it in trace file.